# Rails (agile web development with rails 4th edition) Syntax Error in Controller(products_controller)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using the book: agile web development with rails 4th edition. The error

```
**SyntaxError in ProductsController#index
C:/Users/******/Ruby Tutorial/depot/app/controllers/products_controller.rb:72: syntax error, unexpected $undefined, expecting tSTRING_CONTENT or tSTRING_DBEG or tSTRING_DVAR or tSTRING_END ...ams.require(:product).permit(:\, :title, :description, :imag... ... ^**
```

line 72 is:

```
params.require(:product).permit(:\, :title, :description, :image_url, :price)
```

Is their a syntax error?

code around line 72 is:

```
def product_params
      params.require(:product).permit(:\, :title, :description, :image_url, :price)
    end
end
```

Can anyone help fixing this problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error here is because you've added `:\` as a permitted parameter. Do you have a parameter called `\`?

Answer (score 0):

"...
**Per footnote 5 on page 76,** ***“Windows users will need to put the entire command on one line, without the backslash***”.

Since you are just getting started, it might be easiest to remove the entire depot folder and start afresh.
..."

[same case here](https://forums.pragprog.com/forums/66/topics/2365)